# autocomplete is not recognized as a function, Azure platform

Tags: jquery, azure, jquery-ui, .net-core

I am making a test site, I am getting and TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...c.autocomplete...'). How can I fix that? 
http://icebox29.azurewebsites.net

Comment: you forgot to include **jquery-ui.js**  and **jquery-ui.css**

Comment: I have them jquery-ui.js and  jquery-ui.css  in the js folder and CSS folder. When I call the scripts in the _layout.cshtml, it will fail to load them.

Comment: Your references are not correct. I would use `./css/jquery-ui.min.css?v=i09i05Y6IYiSvhH4MmMyPctE9ePmgV2XJWVL6_au5_s` and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like gaetanoM said, I had to put the reference in there.